# Conditional Checks is done intermittently

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Functionality:***

Users have to enter their spendings in the receipt_details page and depending if they have checked a checkbox, the min spending conditions would differ.If they have checked, the minimum spending is $120 else it would be $150.

There are 2 receipt details textfield in the page hence, these will be the following check conditions:

1.) if (receipt_field_1 is more than 120 OR receipt_field_2 is more than 120 OR sum of receipt_field_1 & receipt_field_2 is more than 120) -> user can submit and navigate to the next page. Else, an error msg will appear

2.) if (receipt_field_1 is more than 150 OR receipt_field_2 is more than 150 OR sum of receipt_field_1 & receipt_field_2 is more than 150) -> user can submit and navigate to the next page. Else, an error msg will appear

***Issue:***

At this point, the check condition is **CORRECT** and **CONSISTENT** for the following behaviour:

1.) when either receipt_field_1 or receipt_field_2 is more than the stated value(120 /150), it will allow user to submit and navigate to next page else, error msg

The issue that I am having is the final check SUM condition which is inconsistent: meaning, at times it is able to decipher and calculate if the sum is less than or more than the stated value (120 / 150), at times it is unable to decipher and calculate if the sum is less than or more than

Hence, I am not sure why would this be so for the check SUM condition to be so inconsistent. Please help.

```js
 //AmexCard User
 if ($('#AmaxCardField').is(':checked')) {

   //Check that the input value field is $120 or more else, inform that minimum spending is 120
   if (($("#ReceiptField_1").val() >= 120) || ($("#ReceiptField_2").val() >= 120) || ((($("#ReceiptField_1").val()) + ($("#ReceiptField_2").val())) >= 120)) {

     //Condition Passed
     console.log("Amex user and spent more than 120");

     alert("You are an AMEX member and spent more than 120");
   } else {
     //inform that minimum spending is 120

     alert("You need to spend more than 120");
   }

 } else if ((!$('#AmaxCardField:checked').length)) {

   //Check that the input value field is SGD$150 or more else, inform that minimum spending is SGD150
   if (($("#ReceiptField_1").val() >= 150) || ($("#ReceiptField_2").val() >= 150) || ((($("#ReceiptField_1").val()) + ($("#ReceiptField_2").val())) >= 150)) {

     //Condition Passed
     console.log("Non-Amex user and spent more than SGD150");

     alert("You are an AMEX member and spent more than 150");
   } else {
     //inform that minimum spending is SGD150
     alert("You need to spend more than 120");

   }
 }
```

```html
<form>

  <!-- DropDown Menu to choose Participating Outlet -->
  <select id="dropDownShops_1">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="ReceiptField_1" style="z-index=10; position:absolute; top:390px; left:858px; height:58px; width:265px; outline:0; border: 0; font-size:25px; font-family:'Gothic'; color:#765725; background: transparent;" autofocus>

  <select id="dropDownShops_2">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Please Select Shops ...</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" id="ReceiptField_2" style="z-index=10; position:absolute; top:585px; left:858px; height:58px; width:265px; outline:0; border: 0; font-size:25px; font-family:'Gothic'; color:#765725;  background: transparent;">

  <input type="checkbox" id="AmaxCardField" style="z-index=10; position:absolute; top:690px; left:420px; height:30px; width:30px; outline=0; border: 0; background: transparent;">
</form>
```

PLunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/obkHLkBC7toFo4t30Sfd?p=catalogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any value coming from text field is always a string.

So

```
$("#ReceiptField_1").val()
```

or

```
$("#ReceiptField_2").val()
```

will return a string even if you are putting in numbers.

That means for any numerical operations you first have to convert them to integer like

```
var rf1 = parseInt($("#ReceiptField_1").val())
```

your condition will change to

```
var rf1 = parseInt($("#ReceiptField_1").val());
var rf2 = parseInt($("#ReceiptField_2").val());

if((rf1 >= 150 || rf2 >= 150) || ((rf1+rf2)>=150))
```

Now,

Why it worked for

```
$("#ReceiptField_1").val() >= 120
$("#ReceiptField_2").val() >= 120
```

because there is not operation over the value. Values will be compared as it is.

but if you add 2 values it will be string concatenation not addition because both are strings not numbers.

Comment: Thanks!!great and detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

Parse your strings to number

```
parseInt($("#ReceiptField_1").val()) + parseInt($("#ReceiptField_2").val()) >= 150
```

note: you may want to do some selector caching